# .NET 4 Framework installation freezes Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, .net, .net-4.0

So I had a problem when installing VS2010, it froze during .NET 4 installation. I tried installing standalone Framework installation and during the install it freezes computer completely, demanding a hw reset.

After this (I once managed to install VS2010 completely) computer freezes randomly. Otherwise, without .NET, computer is completely stable and works.

I tried cleaning up with .NET cleaner and .NET and freezes disappeared. I tried installing .NET 4 Framework on a fresh windows 7 installation (64 bit) and I got the same issue as before - installation freezes and subsequent boots show random freezes during windows usage until I remove it with .NET cleaner or restore windows to it's fresh restore point.

This is driving me mad, I need .NET Framework/VS2010, but it looks like it's mission impossible. I don't even know how to diagnose the problem. Hardware is fine, I ran all possible checks (disk, memory, drivers), windows works just fine without .NET Framework, it works in live boot linux... it works. But, .NET does not work. Installation freezes during installation point where it says something like "Installing .NET 4 Framework Client Profile" about 40% its way through. There is no more verbose way to explain where exactly in the process since installer is a single progress bar.

I really hope some one might help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I think the stall at 40% is normal and it can take quite a bit of time to move past that but it does, how long have you waited?

Comment: problem is not a stall, it's freeze, mouse can't move - it's dead. I left it over night. However I have managed to install it with disabling DisabledSessions in registry. Now I get random freezes in window usage "only", which are gone when I remove .NET framework from windows altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a long time on how to solve this, it finally clicked. Numerous registry hacks and other tricks didn't help. It was as simple as disabling 'hybrid sleep' in windows power management. Looks like power management in windows is buggy in how it stores/restores states and that particular way doesn't suit .Net Framework in certain situations/configurations?

Anyways, disabling 'hybrid sleep' works.

**EDIT:** Apparently not. This is driving me nuts. Freezes are still here.

**FINAL EDIT:** After some more experimentation, it boiled down to .Net NGEN service that, looks like it, has some issues with AMD. After disabling that service (it serves for speedup of .Net programs), everything works fine (including .Net programs) and computer has been running for lots of hours at a time without a single freeze. Case closed.